# What to do if response (or label) columns are in another data frame?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, predict

I'm newbie in machine learning, so I need your advice.

Imagine, we have two data sets (df1 and df2).
First data set include about 5000 observations and some features, to simplify:

```
     name age company degree_of_skill average_working_time alma_mater
1    John  39       A              89                   38    Harvard
2   Steve  35       B              56                   46        UCB
3    Ivan  27       C              88                   42        MIT
4    Jack  26       A              87                   37        MIT
5  Oliver  23       B              76                   36        MIT
6  Daniel  45       C              79                   39    Harvard
7   James  34       A              60                   40        MIT
8  Thomas  28       B              89                   39   Stanford
9 Charlie  29       C              83                   43     Oxford
```

The learning problem - to predict productivity of companies from second data set (df2) for next period of time (june-2016), based on data from the first data set (df1).

df2:

```
  company productivity       date
1       A         1240 april-2016
2       B         1389 april-2016
3       C         1388 april-2016
4       A         1350   may-2016
5       B         1647   may-2016
6       C         1272   may-2016
```

So as we can see both data sets include feature "company". But I don't understand how I can create a link between these two features. What shoud I do with two data sets to solve the learning problem? Is it possible?

Comment: join the data sets, use `pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on='company')`.

Comment: @shivsn and how do you think, should I exclude variable "name" from model?